# Why does Option Explicit still allow implicit For loops in Visual Studio?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, variables, variable-declaration

Consider the following code:

```
Sub Foo()
    For i = 0 To 100
        'Do stuff
    Next
End Sub
```

When I turn `Option Explicit` **ON**, the compilation should fail, because `i` is not explicitely declared. In fact when I compile such code using the `VBCodeProvider` it fails with the correct error

> (BC30451): "i" is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

This is the expected behaviour.

However, when I have this code in a Visual Studio project, it compiles just fine, no matter how I set `Option Explicit`. It does not matter if I enable the option in the project settings or in the code file.

This seems to only be the case in `For` loop counter variables. For other cases like

```
Sub Foo()
    Stuff = 3
End Sub
```

it throws a compile time error in Visual Studio as well. So `Option Explicit` works but seems to be ignored for the `For` counter.

How is this possible? I could not find any information about this and I wonder if there are additional cases like this. It's a bad habit I have developed to write For counters implicitely and it was always silently ignored by Visual Studio - which I consider bad.

I am using Visual Studio 2015, but it was the case for previous versions as well.

Comment: You're mixing up `Option Explicit` and `Option Infer`.

Comment: @Enigmativity A bit of both actually. I could also turn Explicit Off for it to work in the VBCodeProvider example, or Infer On. A bit weird but Tim's answers explains it well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's allowed because that is the way a `For`-loop was designed in VB.NET. 
The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx) explains it all, especially the *optional* [`Counter`-argument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx#BKMK_Counter):

```
Is datatype present?    Is counter already defined?    Result 
                                                      (whether counter 
                                                      defines a new local variable 
                                                      that’s scoped to the entire For...Next loop)
......
No                      No                            Yes. The data type is inferred 
                                                      from the start, end, and step expressions. 
                                                      For information about type inference, 
                                                      see Option Infer Statement and Local Type Inference (Visual Basic).
......
```

Your example:

```
For i = 0 To 100
    'Do stuff
Next
```

The type is inferred from the counter-arguments. Since `0` and `100` are integers the type is `System.Int32`.

---

It's worth mentioning that this is related to the [`Option Infer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb384665.aspx)-statement which you use to enable/disable  local type inference in declaring variables. But for-loop work this way even if you disable type inference.

Don't confuse `option infer on` with with `option explicit off`, there's no difference in performance or type safety compared to code written with the same types explicitly declared.

[Option Infer Statement and Local Type Inference (Visual Basic).](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384937.aspx)

Comment: Ah Option Infer explains the difference between VS and the VBCodeProvider. I have overlooked this. Great answer.